# running node package manager to build but got error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to run a react project with `npm run build` and experiencing the following bugs from the terminal!

Any idea to debug it...?

[image: terminal error]

Comment: I think the issue is may be you didn't install react-dom
`npm install react react-dom --save`

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping the function when it should be like the below and you need to make sure you type npm install --save react react-dom

```js
// ... rest of component
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { term: '' };
  },
// ... rest of component
```